# Adding ASMX (.net) web service client in Netbeans/java? Getting NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, web-services, java

Hey Folks. I was wondering if anything special is required to add a .NET web services to the "Services" tab in NetBeans to allow my java app to consume a .NET web service.

I go and add my WSDL (simple method, 1 operation, takes a string), and I continuously get a NullReferenceError as below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.model.wsdl.impl.WsdlModel.getServices(WsdlModel.java:65)
 at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.wsdl.websvcmgr.WebServiceManager.addWebService(WebServiceManager.java:142)
 at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.saas.wsdl.websvcmgr.WsdlDataManagerImpl$1.run(WsdlDataManagerImpl.java:79)
 at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1957)
```

Is this something common?

I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1 and yes, the webservice is a stub that takes a string and displays a static message right now.

Comment: I just tried this with public webservice at http://service.ecocoma.com/marketing/google.asmx?WSDL, and got the same error :( Is there an alternate method for me to add a webservice client?

Comment: You should say which version of NetBeans. Also, try this with a "hello, world" web service and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot :) I needed to install the SOAP plugin then bam everything works. Sorry for wasting everybodys time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Installing (Tools->Plugins) the SOAP web services plugin fixed my problem. Duh!